# How do you mock out the File Picker in the browser for unit testing?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, jasmine

I am interested in how to **globally mock out the file picker** in the browser. Specifically, I am most interested in doing this in **Firefox** but would prefer a general solution.

I only care about preventing the file picker dialog from appearing. I do not need to be able to assert that it did open. The problem is that I have unit tests for JavaScript code that open the file picker. When the dialog opens, it **halts the execution of the test suite**.

An example situation is that I am testing the `onRender` method of a `Backbone.View`. That method renders a subview, which will open the File Picker when it is rendered. Since I am not directly testing that subview, I would prefer not to mock out portions of its behavior when I am only interested in unit testing some other part of the `onRender` method.

Example:

```
//Test file
it("should do something", function() {
  var view = new App.Views.SomeView();
  spyOn(view.modelBinder, "bind");
  view.render();
  expect(view.modelBinder.bind).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

//View file
onRender : function () {
  this.modelBinder.bind(this.el, this.model);
  this.$("#thing").html(this.subview.render().el); //This line has a side effect that opens file picker
}
```

Essentially, I do not want to explicitly mock out the behavior that causes the file picker to be opened because it is not what I am interested in testing here. Doing so will make the test suite much more brittle and difficult to maintain.

Comment: Using are you using js-test-driver?

Comment: Do me a favor and add the unit test and comment the line where the function that displays it is called.

Comment: Added some code and explanation of the situation.

Comment: To answer your first question, no. I am using Jasmine as my testing framework.

Comment: does this help (do a text search for filepicker in this page)? http://www.eng.uwaterloo.ca/twiki/bin/view/Linux/FirefoxLockdown

Comment: While I think this would probably work, I need the browser to otherwise remain fully functional when not running the suite and I need to avoid requiring custom browser configuration because the suite is run by multiple people across multiple machines.

Comment: I'm really surprised that there is nothing to be found on the internet about this. best of luck to you -- i'm curious to see what you find out.

Answer (score 1):

Use [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) to mock/spy/stub out the calls.  You can test for the calls being made instead of actually making the calls.

That way you can test that the function has been called without calling the actual function that displays the dialog.

Comment: I would prefer not to do this because it varies across the suite what causes the file picker to open. I would rather be able to globally prevent the picker from opening.

Comment: Added some explanation above about why I don't want to stub out the specific methods/events that are resulting in the file picker being opened.

Comment: @AndrewHubbs If your unit tests are dependent on an API other than the API you are writing, you are doing unit testing wrong, it then becomes integration testing instead of unit testing.

Comment: Unit testing means exactly that...testing a single unit of functionality within the software to work the way you expect it to work.  That said I don't know anything about jasmine.js

Comment: Thanks for the lecture on the philosophy of unit testing. It was both informative and useful.

Comment: (of course you're allowed to use another Unit testing API such as Sinon)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: **Just don't.**

I would replace `subview.render()` with an empty function to avoid the undesired side effect. You say however:

> "I **do not want to explicitly mock** out the behavior that causes the
>   file picker to be opened because it is **not what I am interested in testing**..."

Which is a little contradictory. If you want to Unit-Test `App.Views.SomeView`, you **will** have to mock out external collaborators, **specially** when not interesting, and including your file picker. On the other hand, you should not mess with the [SUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) when unit-testing it.

Mocking would in fact make your test more *prone to be red*, but is the only way to make sure your production code does not suffer from ill forms of coupling (IMHO, A common pitfall with Backbone.js apps.)

The only place in which you would need to avoid the file-picker to display, is when unit-testing your file-picker itself, in that case you could use sinon as sugested or leave it without coverage if you are using jQuery. Remember the *"Never mock a type you don't own"* rule.